# Chance letter a next to b in circle with whole alphabet such that no vowels next to each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Here's a question from a book on probability I'm working through:

> If the $26$ letters of the alphabet are written down in a ring so that no two vowels come together, what is the chance that *a* is next to *b*?

Here's what I did. Let's fix *a*. Since *b* can be immediately to the left or right of *a*, there's $2$ choices for *b*. Without loss of generality let's say we have *ab*, and so we have $4$ vowels remaining and $20$ consonants remaining. With the condition that no $2$ vowels come together: We want to find the number of possible places where we can place a vowel, which is in between consonants. With the $20$ consonants, there's $19$ possible "gaps" between, plus the $2$ on the end, for a total of $21$. However, because our *b* already occupies one of them, we have to subtract $1$, getting us $20$. So out of these $20$ places we're choosing $4$, so there's $\binom{20}{4}$ ways to place our $4$ vowels among the $20$ consonants subject to the condition no $2$ vowels come together. There's $4!$ ways to order the remaining vowels and $20!$ ways to order the remaining consonants. So our numerator is$${{2 \binom{20}{4} 20!4!}}$$Now let's calculate the denominator. Fix *a* again. This time we have $21$ consonants and $4$ vowels remaining, but only the $20$ possible "gaps" between the consonants to places our $4$ vowels (there's no $2$ at the end this time around), so our numerator is$$\binom{20}{4}21!4!$$Therefore the chance that *a* is next to *b* is$${2\over{21}}$$However, the answer in the back of my book (which is known to be wrong in many places in the answers in the back section) is ${1\over{10}}$. So who's correct? And if I'm wrong, where did I specifically go wrong?

Comment: I _think_ you might have a fencepost issue.  If you imagine the 20 consonants in a straight line,  then the gap before the first is the same as the gap after the last, since they loop around and connect.

Comment: Note that you would get $\frac 1{10}$ if you treated "y" as a vowel. So if the rule for vowels is "a,e,i,o,u, and sometimes y" then sometimes you are right and sometimes the book is right (:

Comment: @Emperor Concerto Can you please write the name of that book ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler reasoning: We have $26-5=21$ consonants. We know that, in the allowed configurations, each vowel (in particular, $a$) will have two consonants on each side. By symmetry, any pair of consonants is equiprobable. There are $\binom{21}{ 2}=210$ such (unordered) pairs. Among them, there are $20$ pairs that include $b$. Then the probability of our event (letter $a$ is next to $b$) is

$$ p=\frac{20}{210}=\frac{2}{21}=0.95238\cdots$$

which agrees with your answer.